# Entity Framework - Make Category field not required

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, poco

I have two POCO objects:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So obviously, when I create a Product, I can select a category for that product. Or rather, a category is required.

I can't create a product without explicitly selecting a category, and my data is structured in such a way, that I don't want to create a "No Category" category entry.

I've thought about doing a many-to-many mapping between these two tables... but would like to avoid it if possible.

Either I'm doing something silly, or there really is no way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make the `CategoryID` nullable. If you do not supply value for `CategoryID` it will be set to `NULL` in database.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which just goes to show, sometimes it just helps to know what search term you need to look for. Now that I look for the term 'nullable', I find plenty of entries! Thanks for the help, it worked perfectly.